# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract (sorting)

Tags: comparison, comparator

I have an exception when I want to sort my alert list. I know that there are some people who have asked the same question with me. But I really don't have any idea which part of my code causing this exception.
Below is my coding part for sorting the alert list:

```
Collections.sort(listAlert, new Comparator()
    {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
        {
            int i = ((Alert)o1).getAlertType().compareTo(((Alert)o2).getAlertType());
            if(i == 0)
            {
                return (int)(((Alert)o1).getTime() - ((Alert)o2).getTime());
            }
            else return i;
        }
    });
```

Note: getAlertType() method will return the alert type in String and getTime() method will return the alert creation date in millisecond (long)

I really need you help.
TIA,

Tenlee

Comment: Is there a stacktrace you can provide?

Comment: What version of Java are you running?

Comment: @Scott M : I don't have the stacktrace cause I only print the message (e.printMessage()) on my try catch.

Comment: @Idos : I'm using java 1.7 but I set to JDK 6 for the binary format.